# Different behaviour of enumitem in similar preambles

Tags: enumerate

I am using the following two preambles to write different types of documents. In the first, the environment

```
\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
\item First item
\item Second item
\end{enumerate}
```

Gives lists with lowercase roman numerals

[image]

and in the second, it gives lowercase roman numerals, but with a different font.

I tried changing `amsart` to `article` and viceversa, but that did not affect this. How is this controlled?

[image]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%% FIRST PREAMBLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[a4paper,11  pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[top=4cm, bottom=4cm, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,amsrefs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{ytableau}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}
\usepackage{stackrel}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem} 
\usepackage{stmaryrd} 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\onehalfspacing 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\section}{\normalfont}{\normalfont\large}{}{}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{euler}
\usepackage{multicol}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%% SECOND PREAMBLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[a4paper,11  pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=4cm, bottom=4cm, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}

%%%%%%%%%%% PAQUETES BASICOS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,amsrefs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{euler}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={blue!50!black},
    citecolor={red!50!black},
    urlcolor={magenta!80!black}
}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{ytableau}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}
\usepackage{stackrel}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{solution/print=false}
\SetupExSheets{headings=runin-nr}

\usepackage{setspace} 
\onehalfspacing 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{xfrac}
```

Comment: please post as two separate documents demonstrating the effect (and remove any packages that you can remove while still showing the difference)

Comment: In the second case it uses small caps for roman numerals. Much nicer, in my opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is in loading `babel` with the Spanish option.  If you want the Spanish to behave like the English, you can load `babel` with the `spanish.lcroman` option (this is documented in the documentation for the `spanish` babel style (`texdoc spanish` will find it.))  If you want your English document to look like the Spanish you either need to redefine `\roman` or (probably preferably) use the longer form of the `enumitem` label key: `label=(\roman*),format=\textsc`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
\item foo
\item bar
\item foobar
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
\item foo
\item bar
\item foobar
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great. I would have never guessed enumeration style changes with language.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Some of the `babel` styles (French and Spanish to name two I'm aware of) implement substantial changes to conform with the particular typographical practices used in those languages.  These changes includes spacing after punctuation and list styles among other things.